# What database should I use in an app where my models don't represent different ideas, but instead different types with overlapping fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, web-applications, schema, database

I'm building an application where I will be gathering statistics from a game. Essentially, I will be parsing logs where each line is a game event. There are around 50 different kinds of events, but a lot of them are related. Each event has a specific set of values associated with it, and related events share a lot of these attributes. Overall there are around 50 attributes, but any given event only has around 5-10 attributes.

I would like to use Rails for the backend. Most of the queries will be event type related, meaning that I don't especially care about how two event types relate with each other in any given round, as much as I care about data from a single event type across many rounds. What kind of schema should I be building and what kind of database should I be using?

Given a relational database, I have thought of the following:

1. Have a flat structure, where there are only a couple of tables, but the events table has as many columns as there are overall event attributes. This would result in a lot of nulls in every row, but it would let me easily access what I need.
2. Have a table for each event type, among other things. This would let me save space and improve performance, but it seems excessive to have that many tables given that events aren't really seperate 'ideas'.
3. Group related events together, minimizing both the numbers of tables and number of attributes per table. The problem then becomes the grouping. It is far from clear cut, and it could take a long time to properly establish event supertypes. Also, it doesn't completely solve the problem of there being a fair amount of nils.

It was also suggested that I look into using a NoSQL database, such as MongoDB. It seems very applicable in this case, but I've never used a non-relational database before. It seems like I would still need a lot of different models, even though I wouldn't have tables for each one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Build you database to minimize the compute time for retrieving the query types you will be interested in.  Adding records is typically much less expensive than queries.

Comment: Perhaps a list of hashed transaction numbers under each 'attribute'. That way you would easily have the quantity of transactions for each attribute available and also be able to index back into individual transactions should you want to.

Comment: A map or a graph, as opposed to records based, would minimize the storage requirements for null fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a great use case for MongoDB and a very awkward fit for a relational database.

The types of queries you would be making against this data is very key to best schema design but imagine that your documents (in a single collection similar to 1. above) look something like this:

```
{  "round" : 1,
   "eventType": "et1",
   "attributeName": "attributeValue",
   ...
}
```

You can easily query by round, by eventType, getting back all attributes or just a specified subset, etc.

You don't have to know up front how many attributes you might have, which ones belong with which event types, or even how many event types you have.  As you build your prototype/application you will be able to evolve your model as needed.

There is a very large active community of Rails/MongoDB folks and there's a good chance that you can find a lot of developers you can ask questions and a lot of code you can look at as examples.

I would encourage you to try it out, and see if it feels like a good fit.  I was going to add some links to help you get started but there are too many of them to choose from!
Since you might have a question about whether to use an object mapper or not so here's a [good answer to that](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/iXPAaAnsGoE).

A good write-up of dealing with dynamic attributes with Ruby and MongoDB is [here](http://paul-wong-jr.blogspot.com/2012/03/dynamic-attributes-and-mongodbmongoid.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. The question that comes up now is: how do my documents look? Would I have around 50 or so different models, resulting in that many different documents, or is there a way to simplify the structure?

Comment: It would help if you could expand and refine what form you want to show your data in.  I'm not getting a clear idea from you post sofar and it seems like maybe you are not clear yourself.

Comment: All your documents look like the example I gave, just the attributeName sets will be different for different event types.  Your comment about "different models" seems to be still in fixed schema relational realm.  The nice thing about document databases is the schema is flexible.

Comment: @starbolin - I will need to show data in graph form, which involves pulling all kinds of event data.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - I understand how I could dynamically query with MongoDB, but what about the Rails models themselves? Do they not need to have every field pre-defined in the Event class?

Comment: See the last link in my answer.  You don't need to use a mapper/framework.  But if you do, this is a very common question - keeping either attribute key-value pairs or arrays of subdocuments representing attributes where name is stored along with value {"attrname":"name","attrvalue":"value"} and there are other ways. Different mappers have slightly different approaches here.  Here's a good link that talks about dynamic attributes http://paul-wong-jr.blogspot.com/2012/03/dynamic-attributes-and-mongodbmongoid.html

Comment: That link is absolutely perfect, thank you. I'm definitely using MondoDB. Accepted.

Comment: I put that link in the answer - I agree, it's a thoughtful write-up with good example code.

Comment: Mbadov writes: "...show data in graph form,..."   Graph of what, exactly?  Sums, counts,  averages, and etc.?   And I assume you mean a chart, like in Excel.  Not logical graphs like in game theory?     How big a dataset are we talking about?    I'm not seeing the concern about nulls, especially if it's not a flat database.

Comment: Graphs of sums and averages, yes. The dataset will easily be a few million rows. I think MongoDB better fits my needs than a relational database.